# How to find a control using its name?

Tags: c#, silverlight, variables, reference, controls

I'm doing a silverlight project and inside a user control I have lots of checkboxes. I have another list that contains certain strings, for each string existing in this list I want to check its corresponding checkbox.

I named the checkboxes with the strings in the list. But how can I use a variable name for the checkbox name so that I don't have to write down each chkbox name ?

Example: I want to do something like this

```
 foreach (string subject in mylistofsubjects)
 {
      [subject].Checked=true;

 }
```

Is this possible ? or any workarounds can be done ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`FindName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, if you're sure it exists and it has proper type then:

```
foreach (string subject in mylistofsubjects)
    ((CheckBox)FindName(subject)).Checked = true;
```

Call `FindName()` of right container (here I assume it's `this`). If they're nested inside multiple panels then you may need to walk through visual tree, read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189034%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for more information. For an example take a look to [this library](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2010/03/04/linq-to-visual-tree.html), you'll be able to write this:

```
foreach (string subject in mylistofsubjects)
    ((CheckBox)this.Descendants().First(x => x.Name == subject)).Checked = true;
```

Or simply:

```
this.Descendants()
    .Where(x => mylistofsubjects.Contains(x.Name))
    .Cast<CheckBox>()
    .Checked = true;
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks !! I didn't even know such a method exists